# Interface "Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser" not found

Tags: php, laravel

what can be the possible cause of this error, I am using laravel filament for admin,
I got this error when I pushed to production, but it is working fine on local
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [section on the documentation](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/installation#deploying-to-production) about it in the docs.

TL;DR
Filament needs the `FilamentUser` on the model you're using to authenticate, so you have to implement the following on your User model:

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Filament\Models\Contracts\FilamentUser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 
class User extends Authenticatable implements FilamentUser
{
    // ...
 
    public function canAccessFilament(): bool
    {
        return str_ends_with($this->email, '@yourdomain.com') && $this->hasVerifiedEmail();
    }
}
```

Change the authorization logic to fit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when deploying to staging.

Turns out the filament folder wasn't created in the Vendor folder with `composer update`

`composer install` seemed to do the trick